# Using webpack with an existing Node project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to webpack, and am trying to get my head around how I can switch an existing project to using it (am now using React in parts of it, so it has become necessary).

The kinds of things I am uncertain about:

1. As the package.json contains all my server side stuff too, will it not try to compile all this into the bundle.js?
2. My project contains a huge number of statically served files, and also a load of EJS generated pages. What's the best method for converting everything to webpack, I'm thinking it's going to be a bit of a headache to switch everything to 'require' statements instead of  tags, but I guess it's the only way of taking full advantage of the benefits of webpack? Are there any recommended methods (or even scripts that will handles these changes for me?!).

Answer (score 0):

1. Webpack will take care of "tree shaking" for you -- that is, it will only include the modules that your entry points explicitly use, no matter what is in your `package.json` file.
2. Looks like there is some support for EJS already in Webpack. A good conversation of it is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-simple-loader#purpose You can then transition gradually (or not at all) as need be.

Answer (score 0):

1.The backend dependencies in your package.json is unrelated to your frontend stuff. You just need to indicate the correct entry points.

FYI [Entry Points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx)

2.My suggestion is that you can find one EJS loader in GitHub to solve it.

FYI [Loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/)

Comment: So, if my controller is index.js which has expressjs routes for ejs files in views/ and static files in public/assets/, should index.js still be my entry point despite the fact it's a controller and has all the server stuff? If not, what is my entry point, one of the ejs files? or...?

Comment: Now your project on frontend part is designed as a single page structure or not.I mean whether you render the whole page everytime when you received a request in your expressjs routes or you render the page once and just use backend as REST api.If your project isnt a single page structure, I suggest you do not use webpack because it was designed for single page application, you can use gulp instead.

Comment: I dont know much about react, but entry point should be the javascript file includes the codes which render yours react component on your root html element, if you have several files like this or you don't have router system on your react part.Then your project isn't a single page application.

Comment: Ok so now I'm thinking everything I have done is wrong, so wanted to learn webpack as that seems important right now. But webpack = SPA? And SPA = total rewrite...